# VBS passing variable to recursive sub

Tags: variables, vbscript

I am a relative newbie with VBS and scripting in general. I've got a housekeeping script which among other things clears empty folders which I've got a bit of trouble with, hopefully someone can tell me where I am going wrong..

Here is my sub

```
sub clearfolder(folder) 'Recursive search for old empty folders
For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders
    If Subfolder.Files.Count = 0 And Subfolder.SubFolders.Count = 0 Then
        Logwrite "The folder:" & Subfolder.Path & " is empty and will be removed"
        redim preserve arrFolders(arrpath)
        arrFolders(arrpath) = Subfolder.Path
        foldersDeleted = foldersDeleted + 1
        arrpath = arrpath + 1
    else
        Logwrite "The folder:" & Subfolder.Path & " Contains files or folders"
    End If
    clearfolder Subfolder
Next
end sub
```

When I call the sub..

This works:

```
clearfolder objFSO.GetFolder ("F:\Scripts\file_cleardown\Testing\_UK")
```

This doesn't work: (strVariable is above path)

```
clearfolder objFSO.GetFolder (strVariable)
```

Could anyone explain why I can't seem to pass a variable which contains a path instead of the full path? I've tried various ways to pass the path as a variable but I usually get the below error.

```
---------------------------
Windows Script Host
---------------------------
Script: F:\Scripts\file_cleardown\bill_cleanup.vbs
Line:   70
Char:   2
Error:  Object required: 'folder'
Code:   800A01A8
Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error message says you tried `clearfolder strVariable` rather than `clearfolder objFSO.GetFolder (strVariable)`. If that's not the case, please show the full non-working code.

Comment: I think I've resolved this, looks like a simple syntax error, thanks!